# Weighted Median If in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, conditional-operator, median

I have an Excel data tab that has the following columns:
A: County Name
B: Hotel Name
C: # of Rooms in the Hotel
D: Year Hotel Was Constructed

In my analysis tab, I have the following columns:
A: County Name
B: Median Age of a Hotel Room

I am trying to find the median age of a "hotel room" in each county.  In Excel parlance, I am trying to do a weighted MEDIAN IF - take the median if the county name matches weighted by the number of rooms - so if there are three hotels in the county, one built in 1900 w 100 rooms, one built in 1975 with 50 rooms, and one in 2000 with 200 rooms, the value returned should be 2000.  Any help is very much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a few auxiliary columns:
[image]

Prepare them in the following order:

Column E to keep track of how many rooms this hotel and other hotels that are in the same county and were constructed earlier have:

```
E2 = SUMIFS($C$2:$C$15,$A$2:$A$15,"="&A2,$D$2:$D$15,"<="&D2)
```

Column I and J to store how many rooms this county has, and half of that

```
J2 = SUMIFS($C$2:$C$15,$A$2:$A$15,"="&I2)
K2 = J2/2
```

Column F for how far E is to K, and median occurs at the first hotel that passes the mid point.

```
F2 = E2-VLOOKUP(A2,$I$2:$K$4,3,0)
```

Column L to find the minimum positive value that surpasses the midpoint:

```
{L2 = MIN(IF(($A$2:$A$15=I2)*($F$2:$F$15>=0),$F$2:$F$15,""))}
```

and finally Column M to look up the year from I and L against G=A&F:

```
M2 = INDEX($D$2:$D$15,MATCH(I2&L2,$G$2:$G$15,0))
```